# How to extract the session token from Login response in Python?

Tags: python, json, api, session-variables, algorithmic-trading

The code is:

```
samco=StocknoteAPIPythonBridge() 
login=samco.login(body={"userId":'XY1234','password':'XY@12345','yob':'1995'})
print("Login details",login)
```

It's output comes as:

```
Login details {
  "serverTime": "19/01/21 23:25:34",
  "msgId": "8272f7af-9aa8-4800-abe0-952696a3845",
  "status": "Success",
  "statusMessage": "Login session token generated successfully ",
  "sessionToken": "67426552e3bd0ab285c5d7f64a39aa8v",
  "accountID": "XY1234",
  "accountName": "SHIVAM TAWARI",
  "exchangeList": [
    "BSE"
  ],
  "orderTypeList": [
    "MKT",
    "L",
    "SL"
  ],
  "productList": [
    "MIS",
    "CNC",
    "NRML"
  ]
}
```

I just want to extract the session token and store it into a variable. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `json.loads(login)['sessionToken']`

**Example**

```
import json

login=''' {
  "serverTime": "19/01/21 23:25:34",
  "msgId": "8272f7af-9aa8-4800-abe0-952696a3845",
  "status": "Success",
  "statusMessage": "Login session token generated successfully ",
  "sessionToken": "67426552e3bd0ab285c5d7f64a39aa8v",
  "accountID": "XY1234",
  "accountName": "SHIVAM TAWARI",
  "exchangeList": [
    "BSE"
  ],
  "orderTypeList": [
    "MKT",
    "L",
    "SL"
  ],
  "productList": [
    "MIS",
    "CNC",
    "NRML"
  ]
}'''

token = json.loads(login)['sessionToken']

print(token)
```